# clearing a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, vector

Assume I have defined a class like this:

```
 class foo {
 private: 
    std::vector< int* > v;
 public:
    ...
    void bar1()
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         int *a = new int;
         v.push_back( a );
       }
    };

    void bar2()
    {
       std::vector< int >::iterator it = v.begin();
       for ( ; it != v.end(); it++ )  
         std::cout << (*it);
       v.clear();
    }
 };
```

In short, I push back some pointers in a vector, later I clear the vector. The question is, does this code has memory leak? I mean by clearing the vector, are the pointers deleted properly?

Comment: You actually push only a single pointer to the vector; the `for` loop in `bar1` only executes the `new int;` line since it has no curly braces, and `i+++` is a syntax error and... ah well, I guess this is meant to be pseudocode.

Comment: You also need a vector of int pointers: `std::vector< int* > v;` instead of `std::vector< int > v;`

Comment: @juanchopanza: yeah, fixed...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, the code has a memory leak unless you delete the pointers. If the `foo` class owns the pointers, it is its responsibility to delete them. You should do this before clearing the vector, otherwise you lose the handle to the memory you need to de-allocate.

```
   for (auto p : v)
   {
     delete p;
   } 
   v.clear();
```

You could avoid the memory management issue altogether by using a `std::vector` of a suitable [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Comment: can you please give me straghit method (not the smart ptr)??

Comment: @mahmood It depends on the details of your class, but it is a safe bet that you should do it just before clearing the vector. Iterate over it, deleting each element. *Then* clear it.

Comment: Should this be `std::vector< int* >::iterator`?

Comment: @scohe001 Yes indeed, thanks! I transformed it into C++11 to bypass the issue entirely.

Comment: When to do that vs having to write p = nullptr for example ?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to do: `v.clear();` followed by: `v.shrink_to_fit();`?

Comment: @Boyfinn that would still not de-allocate the objects the pointers point to.

Answer (score 15):

I think the shortest and clearest solution would be:

```
std::vector<Object*> container = ... ;
for (Object* obj : container)
    delete obj;
container.clear();
```

Answer (score 10):

Nope you only clear the vector storage. Allocated memory with 'new' is still there.

```
for (int i =0; i< v.size();i++)
   {
     delete (v[i]);
   } 
   v.clear();
```

Comment: use 'delete' on each iteration. After than use clear to clear the vector. e,g delete(*it)

Comment: for (auto& i : v)
        {
         delete (i);
       } 
       v.clear();                                                                                              is this code correct

Answer (score 6):

You can use `for_each` :

```
std::vector<int*> v;

template<typename T>
struct deleter : std::unary_function<const T*, void>
{
  void operator() (const T *ptr) const
  {
    delete ptr;
  }
};

// call deleter for each element , freeing them
std::for_each (v.begin (), v.end (), deleter<int> ());
v.clear ();
```

Comment: I often wish something like this `deleter` was readily available; I wonder, could you implement it in terms of `std::mem_fun_ptr or `std:fun_ptr` or so?