# Crash when trying to deallocate vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a vector of pointers like so: `vector<Operators*> valid_start = {&negative, &values, &numbers, &bracket_left, &functions};`
When using the following code to deallocate the memory, the program crashes

```
void deallocate_vector(vector<Operators*> & a)
{
    for(int it = 0; it < a.size(); it++)
    {
        delete a[it];
    }
    a.clear();
}
```

I've looked at these threads

[Does vector::erase() on a vector of object pointers destroy the object itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353149/does-vectorerase-on-a-vector-of-object-pointers-destroy-the-object-itself)

[clearing a vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795196/clearing-a-vector-of-pointers)

[Cleaning up an STL list/vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307082/cleaning-up-an-stl-list-vector-of-pointers)

[Deallocating objects stored in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808480/deallocating-objects-stored-in-a-vector)

and cannot see why this code fails.
I've tried this form of deallocation as well, and this also crashes:

```
for (std::vector<Operators*>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
{
     delete(*it);
} 
a.clear();
```

I have effectively copied code verbatim, and it still fails. Why?

EDIT:

The declaration of negative. The rest of the pointers are of the same type

```
struct Operators
{
    std::vector<std::string> members;
    std::vector<Operators*> precedents;
    std::vector<Operators*> followers;
}negative;

negative.members = {"-"};
negative.precedents = {&basic_operators, &values, &numbers, &comma, &bracket_left, &bracket_right, &factorial};
negative.followers = {&bracket_left, &numbers, &values, &functions};
```

Comment: You need to post an [mcve].  From the first line of code it looks like you are storing pointers to stack objects.  You cannot call delete on those.  We need more information to confirm that though.

Comment: If `negative`, ..., `functions` are allocated on the stack, it is normal that such a crash occurs. `delete` should only be used on heap allocated variables. Can we see the declaration of negative ?

Comment: You only `delete` pointers returned from `new`. If the pointers stored in your vector were not, don't call `delete` on them. That's the pedantic answer, but also: in modern C++ you never* call `delete` or `new` directly - you should use `unique_ptr` and `make_unique`, `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` (*never has some exceptions)

Comment: @David If the pointers are not returned from `new`, do you not need to deallocate?

Comment: @Utumno Correct. If you write `int x; int* p = &x;` nothing has been allocated. There is no need to deallocate. If you try to deallocate `p`, you'll crash, because `p` points to a variable on the stack, not a heap allocation.

Comment: @David Thanks, I didn't know that (obviously).

Comment: Terminology niggle: Prefer automatic and dynamic over stack and heap to show respect to systems that have no stacks or heaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly why you should be weary of using & outside very controlled circumstances.

I am not sure what an `Operator` is, presumably some class, so I will give a similar example with a type that is universally understood and explain it. Consider:

```
{ // Some sort of local scope
    int x = 10;
    int* xp = &x;
}
```

The life-cycle of `x` is controlled by the compiler. It exists "on the stack", within the execution frame of the program when it enters local scope. It is created when scope is opened/when it is declared, and is deleted when the scope exits. Note that compiler implementation details might mean it is actually created/deleted at different times (or even never, if it is never used), but you can *assume* that behavior for the most part.

Now, `xp` is a pointer to x. What do you think happens if I delete `xp` and then the compiler deletes the memory behind `x`? The same memory is deleted twice - which is undefined behavior that tends to lead to crashes or worse.

For the purpose of understanding the problem, you might *think of this* as if it were:

```
{
    int* __x = new int;
    int& x = (*__x);
    /////////////////

    x = 10;
    int* xp = &x;
    // now xp == __x

    /////////////////
    delete __x;
}
```

Note this is not actually what the compiler will do; however, this somewhat illustrates the outward behavior of what it actually does.